# Within an epic, emit an action that emits more actions when it completes

Tags: typescript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I would like for the epic for Action1 (below) to emit as an observable, Action3 which then emits Action4 and Action5 when finished.

```
const action1Epic$ = (action$: Observable<IAction1>, state$: Observable<IState>) => 
    action$.pipe(
        withLatestFromState(state$),
        switchMap(([_action, { stateProp }]) => {
            const somethingUninteresting$ = of(action2(stateProp));
            
            const compoundActions$ = of(action3(stateProp)).pipe(
                mergeMap(act =>
                    merge(...[of(action4(act.stateProp)), of(action5(act.stateProp))])
                )
            );
            return merge(somethingUninteresting$, compoundActions$);
        })
    );
```

Action3 has an epic:

```
const action3Epic$ = (action$: Observable<IAction3>, state$: Observable<IState>) => {
    console.log("Action 3 is really happening!")
    return action$.pipe(
       withLatestFromState(state$),
       switchMap(([_action, { stateProp }]) => {
          console.log("API call is happening!");
          return api.doSomething().pipe(
             map(statePropFromResponse => action3Success(statePropFromResponse)
          );
       })
    );
}
```

The result is that I see the log for "Action 3 is really happening!" but never "API call is happening!". In the dispatcher I see that Action1, Action2, Action4, and Action5 are processed, but never Action3.

Comment: You could further debug this by adding `tap(console.log)` before `withLatestFromState` in `action3Epic$` and by doing `withLatestFromState(state$.pipe(tap(console.log))),` still in `aciton3Epic$`.

Comment: I tried this - the first log, from before `withLatestFromState`, never gets printed.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the `action$:` argument from `action3Epic$` ? If so, you could do: `actions$.pipe(shareReplay(1))` so that when what `action3Epic$` returns is subscribed, you'll immediately receive a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `act` itself in the merge arguments.

```js
const compoundActions$ = of(action3(stateProp)).pipe(
  mergeMap(act =>
    merge(...[of(act), of(action4(act.stateProp)), of(action5(act.stateProp))])
  )
);
```

The instance of action3 in your action1 epic - `act` in the `mergeMap` callback - is never emitted as a Redux action, because it's not emitted by the observable returned in the epic (specifically `compoundActions$`).

You do subscribe to an observable that emits that action (the `of(action3(stateProp)` bit), but you only use it to create the 2 other actions,
which are the only ones emitted by `compoundActions$`.

---

*p.s.*

Unrelated but hopefully helpful: you can simplify the way you're creating observables.

`merge(...[of(action4(act.stateProp)), of(action5(act.stateProp))]`

can be simplified to

`from([action4(act.stateProp), action5(act.stateProp)])`

For that matter - and here's where I'm not sure if you're just simplifying existing code for the SO example - if all you need to do is emit action 3, 4 and 5 in that order, you can just do:

```js
const compoundActions$ = from([
  action3(stateProp),
  action4(stateProp),
  action5(stateProp),
]);
```